# Best way to keep the user progress updated

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, flutter, mongoose

I am working on an fitness app and I am required to make such a data structure such that I can keep the user progress for each program he/she has opted in . I am using MongoDB with Node js. What will be the best solution for this problem ? Should server database or use app's LocalStorage to keep the user progress

Answer (score 2):

It highly depends on if the data is supposed to be accessible on other devices and/or be backed up on the cloud.

If you were to save the data in a database, this would allow the possibility to tie the data to accounts to be accessed on any device that a user is logged into.

Otherwise, if you don't plan on having data accessible on other devices and tying data to an account, you could get away with saving the data on the user's local storage.